# Change default gallery images - Currently they are displaying full size imagese

Tags: php, images, gallery

Right now my [page load](http://warhammer.hutber.com/) file size is 350mb... for a website...

The reason is that the gallery is loading in the full size 4000px+ images when they are actually a mere 250px in the page:

[image]

Is it possible to display the smallest thumbmail, or even the large image until the user clicks on the image.

I know PHP but I don't know Wordpress, so I would be happy to write this myself if I could understand where to make these changes.

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

That's **HUGE**!

I have good news. WordPress handles creating image thumbnails. You can add new sizes or use the thumb/medium/large sizes that are baked in. You just have to call [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) with the image size as long as the image are in the media library.

Want to add a new image size for a thumbnail? Call [`add_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) with the width/height and whether or not it should be cropped vs resized.

Comment: Ok, so I should edit the theme files directly :D

Comment: It's best practice to add a child theme and make modifications there rather than in the theme you're using. There may be settings in the theme to change the image size settings. Without knowing more detail about the theme or code, I can't say much more.